# TableView: go to new line at the end of the window

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I tried to explane my issue through and image.

[image]

Comment: i don’t think that’s possible out of the box. you don’t want text in the cells, not even just lines, but the whole table to wrap when it doesn’t fit horizontally. it kinda works against the definition of rows and columns but i imagine it’s possible to override the rendering somehow but i don’t think that’s easy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put all the data columns of each object into 1 cell (either just text or in a custom widget), and use a `QListView` with `LeftToRight` `Flow`. That way your objects are layed out automatically.

Comment: ok, but i need to show the editor delegate on hover data, how can i obtain this if i put data into widget? does not this break model/view?
how can i put data of objects of my vector on a custom model into a widget and show them on a qlistwidget?